# How to only display the mantissa of a number (without the exponent part)

Tags: macros

Is there any command that allows us to extract the mantissa of a number like 2.36e6 so we can get 2.36?

Something like this:

```
\mantissa{2.36e6}
```

Comment: Are you just interested in printing the part before `e`? Are you interested in performing calculations on this value? Are you sometimes going to supply macros to `\mantissa`, as in `\mantissa{\somevalue}`?

Comment: yes I want to supply macros to `\mantissa`, as in `\mantissa{\somevalue}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can extract both the mantissa and the exponent:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mantissa}[1]{%
  \hafid@mantissa#1ee\@nil
}
\def\hafid@mantissa#1e#2e#3\@nil{%
  #1%
}
\newcommand{\exponent}[1]{%
  \hafid@exponent#1ee\@nil
}
\def\hafid@exponent#1e#2e#3\@nil{%
  #2%
}

\begin{document}

Mantissa: $\mantissa{1}$; Exponent: $\exponent{1}$\par
Mantissa: $\mantissa{1.2}$; Exponent: $\exponent{1.2}$\par
Mantissa: $\mantissa{1.2e3}$; Exponent: $\exponent{1.2e3}$\par
Mantissa: $\mantissa{1.2e-3}$; Exponent: $\exponent{1.2e-3}$\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

These macros return nothing if the mantissa or the exponent are not present. An easy modification can return 0 if the exponent is not explicitly given: just replace the definition of `\hafid@exponent` with

```
\def\hafid@exponent#1e#2e#3\@nil{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax
    0%
  \else
    #2%
  \fi
}
```

[image]

A version that also allows symbolic input (a control sequence that eventually expands to a number; the exponent can also be input as `E`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\mantissa}{m}
 {
  \hafid_mantissa:f { \tl_lower_case:n { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \hafid_mantissa:n
 {
  \__hafid_mantissa:www #1 ee \q_stop
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hafid_mantissa:n { f }

\cs_new:Npn \__hafid_mantissa:www #1 e #2 e #3 \q_stop
 {
  #1
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\exponent}{m}
 {
  \hafid_exponent:f { \tl_lower_case:n { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \hafid_exponent:n
 {
  \__hafid_exponent:www #1 ee \q_stop
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hafid_exponent:n { f }

\cs_new:Npn \__hafid_exponent:www #1 e #2 e #3 \q_stop
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #2 } { 0 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Mantissa: $\mantissa{1}$; Exponent: $\exponent{1}$\par
Mantissa: $\mantissa{1.2}$; Exponent: $\exponent{1.2}$\par
Mantissa: $\mantissa{1.2e3}$; Exponent: $\exponent{1.2e3}$\par
Mantissa: $\mantissa{1.2e-3}$; Exponent: $\exponent{1.2e-3}$\par
Mantissa: $\mantissa{1.2E-3}$; Exponent: $\exponent{1.2E-3}$\par

\newcommand{\mynumber}{1.26e10}

Mantissa: $\mantissa{\mynumber}$; Exponent: \exponent{\mynumber}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: due to a misfeature in the current release of `expl3` (release 2016/01/19 r6377), the code doesn't work as intended under XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. The simplest workaround is not allowing `E` as a divider:

```
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\mantissa}{m}
 {
  \hafid_mantissa:f { #1 }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\mantissa}{m}
 {
  \hafid_exponent:f { #1 }
 }
```

Comment: Interestingly, your code works under pdfLaTeX, but it gives incorrect results under both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Can some adjustments be made so that the code works under XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX as well?

Comment: @Mico I think I know what's going wrong (and I blame Joseph for this). `;-)`

Comment: @Mico It seems a bug in `expl3`. The simplest workaround is not allowing `E`.

Comment: Whilst there's a bug in `expl3` here, I'm not sure about using `\tl_lower_case:n` for this operation. These are programmatic (string) operations not text ones (which the experimental case changer is for). Admittedly, at the moment `\str_lower_case:n` is not `f`-type expandable but that can soon be adjusted (it's come up elsewhere so should probably change).

Comment: @JosephWright I was aware that `\tl_lower_case:n` is not really the right approach, but `\str_lower_case:n` isn't either, even if it was  f-expandable, because this would require producing a stringified `e` for the argument delimiter. Doable, but awkward.

Answer (score 11):

You can extract the components (mantissa or exponent) using TeX parameter text matching:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@mantissa#1e#2\relax{#1}
\def\@exponent#1e#2\relax{#2}
\newcommand{\mantissa}[1]{\expandafter\@mantissa#1\relax}
\newcommand{\exponent}[1]{\expandafter\@exponent#1\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\newcommand{\Value}{2.36e6}

Value: \Value

Mantissa: \mantissa{\Value}

Exponent: \exponent{\Value}

\end{document}
```

The "non-user level" macros `\@mantissa` and `\@exponent` expects a parameter text of the form `<m>e<e>\relax` where `e` and `\relax` are *required* in the input stream. The user level macros `\mantissa` and `\exponent` both pass `\relax`, but that means you can only pass numbers/values that uses scientific notation, and therefore necessarily have the notation `<m>e<e>`.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

The following code sets up two Lua functions, named `get_mant` and `get_expo`, which extract the mantissa and the exponent, respectively, from a term such as `-1.23e+45`. The code also provides two TeX "wrapper" macros, named `\GetMant` and `\GetExpo`, which invoke the Lua functions. Thus, `\GetMant{2.36e6}` returns `2.36`, and `\GetExpo{2.34e-56}` returns `-56`.

It is assumed that the inputs of `\GetMant` and `\GetExpo` are either valid numbers expressed in "scientific" notation or macros that evaluate to valid scientific-notation numbers. The code doesn't perform any input sanity checking, though: It assumes that you won't be trying to extract mantissas and exponents from expressions such as `abcdefghi` or `+55+e-66-d`. The main formatting requirement is that the input string contains one (and only one) instance of the letter `e`; `E` is OK too.

Two comments:

- The code is set up to suppress any `+` symbols that may be present at the start of the mantissa and exponent components. If you do want to preserve the `+` symbols, just remove the `tonumber` function calls in the arguments of `tex.sprint`.
- The code can handle the case of an "empty mantissa", i.e., an expression such as `e22`: In such an event, the mantissa is set to `1`. Similarly, the code can also handle the case of an "empty exponent", i.e., an expression such as `1.6e`: the exponent is set to `0`. Even the extreme (and frankly somewhat absurd) empty mantissa/empty exponent case, viz., `e` or `E`, is handled correctly: the mantissa is set to `1` and the exponent is set to `0`. :-)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function get_mant ( s )
  mant = string.gsub ( s, "^(.-)[eE](.-)$", "%1" ) 
  if mant == "" then mant = "1" end
  return tex.sprint ( tonumber(mant) )
end
function get_expo ( s )
  expo = string.gsub ( s, "^(.-)[eE](.-)$", "%2" )
  if expo == "" then expo = "0" end
  return tex.sprint ( tonumber(expo) )
end
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\GetMant[1]{\directlua{get_mant(\luastring{#1})}}
\newcommand\GetExpo[1]{\directlua{get_expo(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\NumA}{-3.45e-678}
\newcommand{\NumB}{+1.23E+45}
\newcommand{\NumC}{e}

$\begin{array}{@{}lll@{}}
\mbox{Input} & \mbox{Mantissa} & \mbox{Exponent}\\
\midrule
\texttt{\NumA} & \GetMant{\NumA} & \GetExpo{\NumA}\\
\texttt{\NumB} & \GetMant{\NumB} & \GetExpo{\NumB}\\
\texttt{e22}   & \GetMant{e22}   & \GetExpo{e22}  \\
\texttt{1.23E} & \GetMant{1.23E} & \GetExpo{1.23E}\\
\texttt{\NumC} & \GetMant{\NumC} & \GetExpo{\NumC}\\
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```